# how to fix the matrix flood fill algorithm in java?

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, matrix, flood-fill

I am having issues with this java Matrix flood fill algorithm. I watched it on you tube but the video was not well-edited. I think I need to call the function but I am not being able to do it please help me out.

package algorithmRecursion;

public class MainClass {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    int a [][] = {{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,1},
        {1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0},
        {1,0,0,1,1,0,1,1},
        {1, 2,2,2,2,0,1,0},
        {1,1,1,2,2,0,1,0},
        {1,1,1,2,2,2,2,0},
        {1,1,1,1,1,2,1,1},
        {1,1,1,1,1,2,2,1},
        };
        
        floodFill(a, 4, 3, 3, 2);
        printMatrix(a);
        

    }
    private static void printMatrix(int[][] a) {
    

}
    static void floodFill(int a[][], int r, int c, int toFill, int prevFill) { // int a[][] is matrix input int r and c is row and column int toFill is what you need to fill and  int prevFill is what had been filled previously 
        int rows = a.length;
        int cols    = a[0].length;
        
        if(r < 0 || r >= rows || c < 0 || c >= cols) {
            return;
        }
        if(a[r][c] != prevFill) {
            return;
        }
        a[r][c] = toFill;
        
        floodFill(a, r-1, c, toFill, prevFill);
        floodFill(a, r,  c- 1, toFill, prevFill);
        floodFill(a, r +1, c, toFill, prevFill);
        floodFill(a, r, c + 1, toFill, prevFill);
        
        
        }
```

}

Comment: maybe better if you include a description of what that code is intended to do in the question. Also explaining expected and actual outputs may help. Since `printMatrix` is empty, it is not printing anything - is that the problem?

Comment: well the output should be like if I change 2 number into 3 then all the 2 number should be changed into 3. I don't even exactly know about it much but that's how on the video i saw